# SQL Server - For Insert trigger

Tags: sql-server

With 'For Insert' trigger, are rows inserted to the table yet when it is triggered?

```
  CREATE Trigger check_availability on Room
       For Insert, Update
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, the [blog](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/setting-the-execution-order-of-triggers-in-sql-server/) entry here talks about trigger precedence and how/what data is being inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

```
FOR | AFTER

    AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must succeed before this trigger fires.

    AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.

    AFTER triggers cannot be defined on views.
```